# Xamarin Forms using Firebase- Display all children into an array

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms

I am trying to display all the ProductName into an array. Any Suggestions?

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRddV.png)

Is it possible to read and display all 'ProductName' in an array?

I want the array to be as follows: ["Black Glasses", "Brown Boots"]

Below is my current code:

[FirebaseHelperClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pTlv.png)

Comment: Yes.  What have you tried so far? Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: public async Task<CartItems> List(int personId, string email)
        {
            var allPersons = await ListTest(email);
            await firebase
              .Child("Users")
              .Child(email)
              .Child("Lists")
              .Child("Cart")
              .OnceAsync<CartItems>();
            //return allPersons.Where(a => a.Price > 1).FirstOrDefault();
            return allPersons.FirstOrDefault();
        }

Comment: please [edit] your question to include additional details.  Code stuffed in a comment is impossible to read.  And what is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: My code only retrieves the first child data, I am having trouble trying to get all the children. I feel the best way to rectify this would be to get all and add them to an array and then display them one by one.

Comment: if you want all, why are you using `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: Please replace the **image** you have for `FirebaseHelperClass` with **text of the code**. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Instead of FirstOrDefault, do `ToArray()` or `ToList()`.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I managed to solve it